# StructureMap WithCtorArg - missing reference?

Tags: structuremap

I'm trying to get started with Structure Map. I'm using version 2.5.3.

I've built a simple boot strapper, but I can't get it to compile. I get the error:

'StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression' does not contain a definition for 'WithCtorArg' and no extension method 'WithCtorArg' accepting a first argument of type 'StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What's the am I missing?

the code I'm try to compile is here:

```
using DomainModel.Abstract;
using DomainModel.Concrete;
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Pipeline; //The only WithCtorArg methods I can find are in this namespace, it didn't help.

namespace WebUI
{
public class ContainerBootstrapper
{
    public static void BootstrapStructureMap()
    {
        // Initialize the static ObjectFactory container
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.ForRequestedType<IProductsRepository>()
                .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SqlProductsRepository>()
                .WithCtorArg("connectionString")
                .EqualToAppSetting("SqlConnection");
        });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class has a non default constructor with simple type arguments like string, int, etc... you can try this:

```
x.ForRequestedType<IProductsRepository>()
 .TheDefault
 .Is
 .OfConcreteType<SqlProductsRepository>()
 .WithCtorArg("connectionString")
 .EqualToAppSetting("SqlConnection");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar issue.

If you're using the generic version of ForRequestedType you have to do as darin suggested and use the **TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType** syntax

If you're using the non-generic version of ForRequestedType you can do it like so:

```
x.ForRequestedType(typeof (ProductsRepository))
 .TheDefaultIsConcreteType(typeof(SqlProductsRepository))
 .WithCtorArg("connectionString")
 .EqualToAppSetting("SqlConnection");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm upgrading an old project to StructureMap 3.1.6.186 and couldn't get WithCtorArg() to resolve.
From documentation here: http://structuremap.github.io/registration/inline-dependencies/ I am now using something like the following instead:

```
x.For<ProductsRepository>()
 .Use<SqlProductsRepository>() 
 .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is("SqlConnection")
```